# How to run a linear regression by row and fill data only in elements with NA in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, regression

I have a data frame containing data on population densities in cities dependent on the distance to the city center ('spatial distance profiles').

The dataframe looks like this (example):

```
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(cities = c("city1","city2","city3"),
    km1 = runif(3,6,7),
    km2 = runif(3,5,6),
    km3 = runif(3,4,5),
    km4 = c(3.5,3.2,NA),
    km5 = c(NA,NA,NA)
)
```

"cities" contains the cityname or an identifier while variables "km1-km4" contain the log of the population density in that distance. Note that observation 3 in the example does not have data for km4; all cities do not have data for km5.

What I am trying to achieve is to extrapolate how many kilometers the city spreads out, when the population density follows an exponential function.

To do so, I want to first run a linear regression y~x for every row of the table, where y is variables km1-kmX and x the corresponding distance to the city center (1,2,3, ...).

```
 lm(km1-kmX ~ distance)
```

(Variable "distance" is not defined in the example, as I do not know how to incorparate it in the dataframe. But I hope the idea comes through)

So, for city1 and city2 variables km1-km4 should be used, while for city3 obviously only km1-km3.

The resulting coefficients beta_0 and beta_1 should then be stored as variables in the corresponding row.

Next, I want to use the coefficients to calulcate the logarithm of population density for the missing variables, kind of:

```
km4 = beta_0 * exp(beta_1*4) #for observation 3
km5 = beta_0 * exp(beta_1*5) #for all observations
```

I know that the description is a little vague; I wanted to be as precice as possible with amplifying all of the details of the idea. Appreciate any help.

Although probably not necessary, this is platform I use R on:
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Comment: Hi, what you are looking for is called Imputation, check out the `MICE` package for this. If you want to do this manually, create a dataset with full rows `data2 <- data[!is.na(km4), ]` run the regession on this new dataset and use the resulting model and the `predict` function to predict `km4` for the cases where it's missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the objective is to fill in the NA values using a linear regression of the non-NA values on the same line vs. the digit in the heading, first extract the numeric values in the column names forming `x`.  Then define a function which regresses the row values against x and predicts the NAs from that.  Finally apply it to each row.

```
x <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", names(data)[-1]))  # c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
na.lm <- function(r, x) ifelse(is.na(r), predict(lm(r ~ x), list(x = x)), r)
cbind(data[1], t(apply(data[-1], 1, na.lm, x = x)))
```

giving:

```
  cities      km1      km2      km3     km4      km5
1  city1 6.265509 5.908208 4.944675 3.50000 2.839583
2  city2 6.372124 5.201682 4.660798 3.20000 2.344337
3  city3 6.572853 5.898390 4.629114 3.75638 2.784510
```

Answer (score 3):

First, I think we need to reshape your data from "wide" to "tall" format. This will satisfy Ryan's comment that you cannot do linear regression with a single row -- he's technically right, but I think he's missing the point that you actually have 4-5 observations per row, not 1. (*Comment since deleted.*)

(Second: "never" name a variable `data`. If you forget to create it in a new R session, all functions that depend on it will fail in a curious and often unintuitive way instead of the expected simpler error message `Error: object 'data' not found`. I will use `dat` with your creation code.)

This is demonstrated using a few packages from the `tidyverse`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
```

Reshaping: first, you enumerate as `km1`, `km2`, etc, but those are categorical variables, not numbers, and I'm inferring that you want the numbers stored in them. So what you have as a column name (`km1`) really should be data (`km = 1`). (Oh, and I remove the `NA`, since they don't help feeding the model. We'll bring them back later.)

```
datlong <- dat %>%
  gather(km, dens, -cities) %>%
  mutate(km = as.numeric(gsub("km", "", km))) %>%
  rename(city = cities) %>%
  filter(complete.cases(.))
datlong
#     city km     dens
# 1  city1  1 6.265509
# 2  city2  1 6.372124
# 3  city3  1 6.572853
# 4  city1  2 5.908208
# 5  city2  2 5.201682
# 6  city3  2 5.898390
# 7  city1  3 4.944675
# 8  city2  3 4.660798
# 9  city3  3 4.629114
# 10 city1  4 3.500000
# 11 city2  4 3.200000
```

Now the problem is how to do a regression on each city. First, let's just "tidy" things up a little by putting all of a city's data in one "cell" of the frame.

```
datnested <- datlong %>%
  group_by(city) %>%
  nest(.key = "citydat")
datnested
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   city  citydat         
#   <fct> <list>          
# 1 city1 <tibble [4 x 2]>
# 2 city2 <tibble [4 x 2]>
# 3 city3 <tibble [3 x 2]>
```

Now we can run a regression on each dataset:

```
datmodel <- datnested %>%
  mutate(model = map(citydat, ~ lm(dens ~ km, data = .x)))
datmodel
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   city  citydat          model   
#   <fct> <list>           <list>  
# 1 city1 <tibble [4 x 2]> <S3: lm>
# 2 city2 <tibble [4 x 2]> <S3: lm>
# 3 city3 <tibble [3 x 2]> <S3: lm>
```

Notice the embedded models in the frame? Each looks something like this:

```
datmodel$model[[1]]
# Call:
# lm(formula = dens ~ km, data = .x)
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)           km  
#       7.470       -0.926
```

Now *that* can be used elsewhere. Let's run a prediction:

```
predkm <- 1:5
datpred <- datmodel %>%
  mutate(pred = map(model, ~ data_frame(km = predkm, preddens = predict(.x, newdata = data.frame(km=predkm)))))
datpred
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   city  citydat          model    pred            
#   <fct> <list>           <list>   <list>          
# 1 city1 <tibble [4 x 2]> <S3: lm> <tibble [5 x 2]>
# 2 city2 <tibble [4 x 2]> <S3: lm> <tibble [5 x 2]>
# 3 city3 <tibble [3 x 2]> <S3: lm> <tibble [5 x 2]>
```

Similarly:

```
datpred$pred[[1]]
# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#      km preddens
#   <int>    <dbl>
# 1     1     6.54
# 2     2     5.62
# 3     3     4.69
# 4     4     3.77
# 5     5     2.84
```

Okay, so how do we get a single resulting frame?

```
datpredonly <- datpred %>%
  select(city, pred) %>%
  unnest()
datpredonly
# # A tibble: 15 x 3
#    city     km preddens
#    <fct> <int>    <dbl>
#  1 city1     1     6.54
#  2 city1     2     5.62
#  3 city1     3     4.69
#  4 city1     4     3.77
#  5 city1     5     2.84
#  6 city2     1     6.37
#  7 city2     2     5.36
#  8 city2     3     4.36
#  9 city2     4     3.35
# 10 city2     5     2.34
# 11 city3     1     6.67
# 12 city3     2     5.70
# 13 city3     3     4.73
# 14 city3     4     3.76
# 15 city3     5     2.78
```

If you want to compare with the original (for errors, etc), try:

```
full_join(datlong, datpredonly, by = c("city", "km")) %>%
  arrange(city, km)
#     city km     dens preddens
# 1  city1  1 6.265509 6.543607
# 2  city1  2 5.908208 5.617601
# 3  city1  3 4.944675 4.691595
# 4  city1  4 3.500000 3.765589
# 5  city1  5       NA 2.839583
# 6  city2  1 6.372124 6.367239
# 7  city2  2 5.201682 5.361514
# 8  city2  3 4.660798 4.355788
# 9  city2  4 3.200000 3.350063
# 10 city2  5       NA 2.344337
# 11 city3  1 6.572853 6.671989
# 12 city3  2 5.898390 5.700119
# 13 city3  3 4.629114 4.728249
# 14 city3  4       NA 3.756380
# 15 city3  5       NA 2.784510
```

So you discussed using an exponential regression: this is handled in the single call to `lm` earlier in the run. Feel free to change from `dens ~ km` to specific exponential formulas.

I had broken all of that into components. Here's the long chain.

```
predkm <- 1:5
datnestedmodels <- datlong %>%
  group_by(city) %>%
  nest(.key = "citydat") %>%
  mutate(
    model = map(citydat, ~ lm(dens ~ km, data = .x)),
    pred = map(model, ~ data_frame(km = predkm,
                                   preddens = predict(.x, newdata = data.frame(km=predkm))))
  )
datnestedmodels %>%
  select(city, pred) %>%
  unnest()
```

If you prefer (or need) it in the "wide" format:

```
datnestedmodels %>%
  select(city, pred) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  spread(km, preddens, sep = "")
# # A tibble: 3 x 6
#   city    km1   km2   km3   km4   km5
#   <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 city1  6.54  5.62  4.69  3.77  2.84
# 2 city2  6.37  5.36  4.36  3.35  2.34
# 3 city3  6.67  5.70  4.73  3.76  2.78
```

Comment: solution works perfectly on my dataset, thank you very much for the detailed description!